# Type-erase owner in self-referential crates

Tags: rust, type-erasure, self-reference

I have a struct, and want to define another struct that references its field.

```rs
struct Tweet {
  text: Text
}

#[ouroboros::self_referencing]
struct BorrowedText<Owner> {
  owner: Arc<Owner>, // make sure it's not deallocated while borrowing
  #[borrows(owner)]
  borrowed: &'this Text,
}
```

There can be many types that have Text as a member. To prevent `BorrowedText<T>` from creating too many types, I would like to erase the owner type.

```rs
#[ouroborus::self_referencing]
struct BorrowedText {
  owner: Arc<dyn Any>, // make sure it's not deallocated while borrowing
  #[borrows(owner)]
  borrowed: &'this Text,
}
```

For this I need to get &Text from `owner: Arc<Tweet>` and then upcast owner to `Arc<dyn Any>`. I couldn't make this work with ouroborus or owning_ref API (owning_ref even has dedicated erased-types like `ErasedBoxRef`).

Is there any way to achieve this with ErasedBoxRef or other API? Or can I just safely do the below without the need for self-referential crates?

```rs
BorrowedText { owner: owner.clone(), borrowed: unsafe { (&owner.text) as (*const Text) } }
```

Comment: Can you provide a (non-working) example of your attempts?

Comment: What about downcasting?

Comment: I wanted to avoid upcast-and-downcast. Is downcasting zero-cost?

Comment: No, it has a check, but 1) there is a good chance the compiler will optimize it away, and 2) do you really need that extra CPU cycle (and that is probably not even one cycle, a well-predicted branch. More like zero cycles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually unsafe-transmuting worked without a cost of dynamic downcast

```rust
fn f(owner: Arc<Tweet>) {
  let borrowed = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<&'_ _, &'static _>(&owner.text) };

  BorrowedText {
    owner: owner as Arc<dyn Send + Sync>,
    borrowed,
  }
}
```